# Creating custom Patch classes of multiple Artists in Matplotlib? (Rectangle + Text)

Tags: matplotlib

Basically, I would like to have a custom patch, that consists of a [matplotlib.patches.Rectangle](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) (which extends `matplotlib.patches.Patch`, which extends `matplotlib.artist.Artist`) and a [matplotlib.text.Text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html) (which extends `matplotlib.artist.Artist`)

The problem is, I absolutely cannot find any working examples of classes that are composed of multiple Patches or Artists, and extend existing Patches.

The initial idea that I got was to extend Rectangle with a new class, and in its init, instantiate a Text - but I had a suspicion this wouldn't quite be to my liking, and I saw it confirmed here:

[How to use a cutom marker in Matplotlib with text inside a shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62466362/how-to-use-a-cutom-marker-in-matplotlib-with-text-inside-a-shape/62466822#62466822)

```py
...
class PlanetPatch(mpl.patches.Circle):
...
    def add_to_ax(self, ax):
        ax.add_patch(self)
        ax.add_patch(self.ring_contour)
        ax.add_patch(self.ring_inner)
        ax.add_patch(self.top)
...
for x in range(100):
...
    planet = PlanetPatch(xy, r, linewidth = 20,
...
    planet.add_to_ax(ax)
...
```

This is what is nagging me: I wouldn't really keep individual reference to children in my subclass, and "manually" do `add_patch` for them individually through a custom function - what I'd want to achieve is a usage like for Rectangle itself:

```py
...
myrect = Rectangle((0,0), 1,20)
mypatch = ax.add_patch(myrect)
...
```

... that is, if the custom class was MyRectangleText, its usage should be the same:

```py
...
mymrt = MyRectangleText((0,0), 1,20, text="Hello")
mypatch = ax.add_patch(mymrt)
...
```

... basically, no calling of special functions; whatever the subclass constructor returns, goes as a single reference into `add_patch` - no matter how many other patches it consists of internally.

On the other hand, I looked at the Rectangle [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.0/lib/matplotlib/patches.py#L663-L879), and it is quite complex - and I find it difficult to believe, that I'd have to rewrite a Rectangle+Text class on that level, especially since both Rectange and Text exist. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to do it in an easy way (inheriting from existing classes).

So, is it possible to create a Rectangle + Text matplotlib class easily (that is, reusing the existing Rectangle and Text classes), such that it is essentially a subclass of Patch (it has to be a subclass of Artist regardless, I guess), and is used in same way -- and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was a bit tricky - but I managed to get somewhere...

After looking at the API, it seemed easiest that the custom class does not in fact extend/inherit from `Patch` (also there is an example that draws multiple `Rectangle` (by way of `Cell`) which extends `Artist` - which is `matplotlib.table.Table`). Mostly because:

- `Rectangle` extends `Patch`, where `Patch` extends `Artist`
- `Text` extends `Artist`

In more detail:

- `Artist` allows for clipping, children, transforms etc, - and it defines a (minimal/skeleton) `draw` method; but it does not "know" about paths or points
- `Patch` introduces concept of a `Path` with points (and related methods), and in addition to the `draw` method, also `get_path` and `set_path` methods (which are the minimum required to extend a `Patch` class, see `PathPatch`)
- `Text` also does not "know" points, and in fact uses a custom renderer in its `draw` method.

Therefore, the lowest common denominator of all three is the `Artist` class with the `draw` method, and that is what the custom class would primarily aim to extend; correspondingly, the objects of this class will be added to the plot not via `add_patch`, but with `add_artist`.

Then, our class can "merely" instantiate the Text and the Rectangle as its child properties, and call their individual `draw` methods in the parent `draw`. It turns out, in addition to `draw`, one should at least also overload `set_figure` and `set_transform`. (Overloading the `axes` getter/setter seems not really required, but without it, the child properties will lack a reference to `_axes`).

Additionally, in the example below, I have also overloaded `set_clip_path` - and that is because I wanted a graphic element which is a rectangle, which clips the text inside - and it turns out, with a custom class like this, we have to handle that manually, along with the clipping of both elements to the plot limits! Unfortunately, the transformations involved are very unclear to me - but I was lucky to find a setup which behaves exactly as I want in terms of plot panning, shown on the animated gif below:

[image: matplotlib plot interaction with custom class]

Finally, here is the code:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.artist as artist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.transforms as mtransforms
import numpy as np

class MyRectangleText(matplotlib.artist.Artist):
  def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, width=0, height=0, textstr="", rectsettings={}, textsettings={} ):
    super().__init__()
    self._x, self._y, self._width, self._height = x, y, width, height
    self._textstr = textstr
    self._textsettings, self._rectsettings = textsettings, rectsettings
    # instantiate children objects
    self._rect = mpatches.Rectangle((self._x, self._y), self._width, self._height, **self._rectsettings)
    self._text = matplotlib.text.Text(self._x, self._y, self._textstr, **self._textsettings)
    # must modify zorder, else is drawn behind the plot!
    # note rect by default has zorder 1, text has zorder 3
    self.update({'zorder': self._rect.zorder})

  def set_figure(self, fig): # gets autocalled by engine 
    super().set_figure(fig)
    self._rect.set_figure(fig)
    self._text.set_figure(fig)

  def set_transform(self, trans): # gets autocalled by engine 
    super().set_transform(trans)
    # "the text does not get the transform!" (Cell)
    self._rect.set_transform(trans)
    self._text.set_transform(trans)
    self.stale = True # not really needed?

  # .axes of self._rect/self._text are None, unless set in the setter here
  # overriding as per https://stackoverflow.com/q/7019643/
  # (setter name is derived from getter name)
  @matplotlib.artist.Artist.axes.getter
  def axes(self):
    return self._axes
  @axes.setter
  def axes(self, new_axes):
    self._axes = new_axes
    self._rect.axes = self._axes
    self._text.axes = self._axes

  #def set_clip_box(self, clipbox): # not autocalled!
  #def set_clip_on(self, b): # not autocalled!

  # note _get_clipping_extent_bbox: "extents of the intersection of the clip_path and clip_box for this artist"

  # set_clip_path is needed, else when dragging in plot,
  # rectangle might appear outside of plot boundaries (axes)!
  def set_clip_path(self, path, transform=None): # gets autocalled by engine 
    super().set_clip_path(path, transform)
    
    # NOTE: cannot really setup both _rect and _text here, such that
    # _rect is clipped at plot bounds (done here); and
    # _text is clipped both by _rect (not done here) and by plot bounds (done here)
    
    self._rect.set_clip_path(path, transform) # clip at bounds of plot - OK
    
    # try: _rect in set_clip_path, and path in set_clip_box:
    """
    self._text.set_clip_path(self._rect) # ok, clips at rect - but only without the next set_clip_box
    self._text.set_clip_box(path.get_extents()) # ok, clips at plot bounds - but overrides the previous set_clip_path(self._rect)
    """
    
    # try opposite:  path in set_clip_path, and _rect in set_clip_box:
    self._text.set_clip_path(path, transform) # ok, clips at plot bounds - but set_clip_box(self._rect.get_extents()) afterwards will override it
    #self._text.set_clip_box(self._rect.get_extents()) # wrong - texts not even shown!

  @artist.allow_rasterization
  def draw(self, renderer):
    super().draw(renderer) # handles get_visible
    self._rect.draw(renderer)
    # note: with self._text.set_clip_path(path..) above,
    # the below set_clip_box(_rect) makes the text be clipped by
    # BOTH the plot area, AND the self._rect area (is clipped by
    # the intersection of those two areas)
    # The only problem is, once text is fully out of plot area,
    # it will be shown fully again, because tbr becomes None - handle!
    tbr = self._rect.get_tightbbox(renderer)
    if tbr is not None:
      self._text.set_clip_box(tbr)
      self._text.draw(renderer)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=None)

x = 0 ; y = 0 ; width = 100; height = 50; 
rect = mpatches.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, linewidth=1, edgecolor='black', facecolor='#AAAAAA88')
patch = ax.add_patch(rect)

rsets = { "linewidth":1, "edgecolor":'black', "facecolor":'green' }
mymrt = MyRectangleText(10,10, 30,5, "Hello World", rsets)
myartist = ax.add_artist(mymrt)

font_size = 40
tsets = { "size": font_size, "color": 'yellow' }
mymrt2 = MyRectangleText(40,30, 45,5, "Hello World", textsettings=tsets)
myartist = ax.add_artist(mymrt2)

plt.show()
```